# IntelliJ Structural Search to find all classes without given declarations

Tags: java, intellij-idea, structural-search

Consider we have a class

```
public class MyTest() {
    @Inject private Class1 class1;
    @Inject private Class2 class2;

}
```

and a class

```
public class MyTest2() {
    @Inject private Class1 class1;
    @Inject private Class2 class2;
    @Inject private Class3 class3;

}
```

I want to find all classes that inject `class1` and `class2` and **DO NOT** inject `class3`. I've tried to use Structural search from IntelliJ but got stuck. Is it doable with structural search?

Comment: How does that injection work, can you give an example how that looks like? As in: something that happens *inside* a method or constructor isn't **structure**, but **code**.

Comment: @GhostCat, maybe I've made a misleading title. Let's say I want to find all classes that declare class1 and class2 but do not declare class3.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe by using search template:

```
class $a$ {
  @Inject private Class1 $_1$;
  @Inject private Class1 $_2$;
  $3$;
}
```

and search text filters  for $_1$    $_2$   and   $_3$:
respectively

```
text=class1
text=class2
text=!@Inject private Class1 class3;
```

Comment: This sounds like a possible solution, thanks! However, it seems to have its limitations:

1) Let's say I want to exclude more classes, that'd require adding them one by one.
2) This solution depends on the order of class declarations.
3) It's not clear how does `text` filter work.

I believe it's possible to enhance the solution by using `script` filter but failed finding proper documentation for it.

Comment: As long as I remember I'v cheked it and it didn't depend on the order of class declarations

Comment: You're probably right, will check soon. However, it will still require defining all the classes you want to prohibit. I'm thinking more about something like `these classes are allowed and others are prohibited`. I see that https://stackoverflow.com/users/4510/bas-leijdekkers knows a lot about SSR, maybe he'll be able to point to a possible solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

I am (still) not sure I understand the problem correctly, but you could try something like this:

```
class $X$ {
    @Inject private Class1 $a$;
    @Inject private Class2 $b$;
    @Inject private Class3 $c$;
}
```

And add a count filter `[0,0]` on `$c$`.

This will find classes that have `Class1` and `Class2` fields, but do not have a `Class3` field.

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo in an original message. There are different Class1 and Class2 and these injections should exist but Class3 should not be imported/declared.